# nifi executescript flowfile creation issue in Python

Tags: python, overriding, apache-nifi

I am scraping a page (e.g., facebook page ) using python script and want to pass on each post to be written to a file (something like gettwitter process). ExecuteScript is first processor in my nifi data flow. I managed to create a flow file using session.create() and no issues in that.

However, I am confused about how to put the data I read from facebook into **outputstreamCallback**. Most of the examples I have seen have used java overriding but I have to use Python and must admit I am little new to that.

I have found so many examples on reading the flow file but nothing much on. Below is something in Java which I want to do in Python.

```
FlowFile flowFile = session.create();
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void process(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.write(tweet.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

If there is any other way, please guide. Thanks.

---

After adopting the changes suggested by @James I wrote a snippet which is given below but not flow file transferred. No compilation error though.

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time
import sys
import traceback
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil

class WriteContentCallback(OutputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content_text = content

    def process(self, outputStream):
        try:
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(self.content_text))
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise

#app_id = "<FILL IN>"
#app_secret = "<FILL IN>" # DO NOT SHARE WITH ANYONE!
page_id = "dsssssss"
#page_id = raw_input("Please Paste Public Page Name:")

#access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret

access_token = "sdfsdfsf%sdfsdf"

#access_token = raw_input("Please Paste Your Access Token:")


def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
        flowFile = session.create()
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("Hello there this is my data"))
        flowFile = session.write()
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)

        has_next_page = False
        num_processed = 0   # keep a count on how many we've processed
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()


        while has_next_page:
            print "Scraping %s Facebook Page: %s\n" % (page_id, scrape_starttime)
            has_next_page = False

        print "\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % \
                (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
    flowFile = session.create()
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("and your data"))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Below is the output from nifi-app.log

```
> [root@ambari logs]# tail -100 nifi-app.log 2017-04-03 14:08:07,989
> INFO [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-6]
> o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled
> ExecuteScript[id=a62f4b97-8fd7-15cd-95b9-505e1b960805] to run with 1
> threads 2017-04-03 14:08:08,938 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2]
> o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller
> org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@44ec5960 // Another save
> pending = false 2017-04-03 14:08:13,789 INFO [StandardProcessScheduler
> Thread-3] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled
> PutFile[id=a62f4b8e-8fd7-15cd-7517-56593deabf55] to run with 1 threads
> 2017-04-03 14:08:14,296 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2]
> o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller
> org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@44ec5960 // Another save
> pending = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of a NiFi OutputStreamCallback in Python ExecuteScript:

```
import sys
import traceback
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil

class WriteContentCallback(OutputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content_text = content

    def process(self, outputStream):
        try:
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(self.content_text))
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise

# Create new FlowFile with content
flowFile = session.create()
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("This is the flowfile content"))
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: the snippet you shared works well if executed standalone. However, when I try to enrich it with python code, I don't get the flow file transferred to next processor (0 bytes transferred) although there is no compilation error.